# How can I assign a value to a variable by passing a string of its name?

Tags: c#, function, variables, methods

Example:

```
int XValue;
int YValue;

void AssignValue(string VariableName,int VariableValue)
{
    VariableName = VariableValue;
}

void CallAV()
{
    AssignValue("XValue", 10);
    AssignValue("YValue", 15);

}
```

So, basically i want to change the value of a variable by knowing its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is collectively called [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx). Specifically, you want to use [`Type.GetField()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e(v=vs.110).aspx). You could do something like this:

```
void AssignValue(string VariableName, int VariableValue)
{
    // Get the non-public instance variable (field)
    FieldInfo field = GetType().GetField(VariableName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Set the variable's value for this instance of the type
    field.SetValue(this, VariableValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. But, what if these variables are of different types mabye XValue is int but YValue is string or bool. how can i change the method parameter to accept any type?

Comment: @Forenkazan Just change `int VariableValue` in the parameters list to `object VariableValue`.